# How to use combiner, when the output VALUE of reducer is null?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When I tried to use combiner in my MR job I am getting the below exception

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IFile$Writer.append(IFile.java:193)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$CombineOutputCollector.collect(Task.java:1315)
>
> at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$NewCombinerRunner$OutputConverter.write(Task.java:1632)

The reason is, I am using **null** as my output VALUE in reducer class.
Reducer Code :

```
public  static class reducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable>{
            public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
                context.write(key, null);
            }
    }
```

When I remove the combiner class **job.setCombinerClass(reducer.class);** job is getting successful.

How can I implement combiner, I need the same reducer output ie with only KEY as output?

Comment: Why not use Optional as of Java or empty object? Or check for null value in your reducer code.

Comment: I am not sure why you are `null`, Did you consider using `NullWritable` instead.

Comment: @YoungHobbit,  I tried NullWritable but I face the same error. Just for testing I tried  **new IntWritable()**, then there is no problem. But the output is not as expected, 0 is appending at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to achieve. The problem is the following piece of code in [IFile.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/IFile.java):

```
public void append(K key, V value) throws IOException {
    .....

    if (value.getClass() != valueClass)
        throw new IOException("wrong value class: "+ value.getClass()
                          +" is not "+ valueClass);

    .....
```

In the `append()` function, there is a check:

```
if (value.getClass() != valueClass)
```

Since you are passing `null` as the value, the `NullPointerException` is thrown, when it tries to `getClass()` on a `null` value:

```
value.getClass()
```

So, even if you use `NullWritable` (which is again a class) and pass `null`, you will still get the `NullPointerException`.

Instead of passing `null`, you should manage by passing 0 (Zero).